# How to improve solution for string concatenation?

Tags: prolog

SWI-Prolog has no list concatenation function, and I have to write it myself. I know the classic solution, but it does not allow access to the head and tail of the second list.

```
conc([], L, L).
conc([X|L1], L2, [X|L3]):-
     conc(L1, L2, L3).
```

How can I add a program to ask questions to the compiler like this?

```
?- conc([_, _, _], [L | [_, _, _]], [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m]).
```

I know that I can write the same thing in the form:

```
?- conc([_, _, _ | L], [_, _, _], [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m]).
```

Comment: You probably want to ask a question like `L = [_,_,_], conc([_,_,_], L, [a,b,c,d,e,f])`? `[L|[_,_,_]]` makes not much sense, since that is the same as `[L,_,_,_]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like

```
conc([_, _, _], [L | [_, _, _]], [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m]).
```

does not make much sense, given you are looking for a *list* `L`. After all `[L|[_,_,_]]` is just equivalent to `[L,_,_,_]`, although the latter is syntactical sugar.

If you are looking for a way to obtain the elements in front of the list, you can just use `conc/3` a second time, like:

```
conc([_,_,_], B, [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m]), conc(L, [_,_,_], B).
```

This gives us the expected result:

```
?- conc([_,_,_], B, [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m]), conc(L, [_,_,_], B).
B = [d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l|...],
L = [d, e, f, g, h, i, j] ;
false.
```

We can make a `conc/4` that splits the list in three parts, like:

```
conc(A, B, C, L) :-
    conc(A, D, L),
    conc(B, C, D).
```

and then query like:

```
?- conc([_,_,_], L, [_,_,_], [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m]).
L = [d, e, f, g, h, i, j] ;
false.
```

Comment: To access the elements of the second string, I can simply use concatenation a second time. Thank. Although I gave a slightly incorrect example, you still answered my question.